# Elasticsearch Filtered Query Results Confusing

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to use a filtered query on an Elasticsearch index that has about 3M documents and I can't seem to get it to work as I would expect.

To elaborate, my query looks like this (my index is for college course information):

```
{
  "query":{
    "filtered":{
      "query":{
        "match_phrase_prefix":{
          "course_abbreviation":"CS 3"
        }
      },
      "filter":{
        "term":{
          "department_id":49599
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This produces no results.  However, if I give an entire "course_abbreviation" (ex: CS 301), I get one result.

To further add to my confusion, if I do the following query:

```
{
  "query":{
    "match_phrase_prefix":{
      "course_abbreviation": "CS 3"
    }
  }
}
```

I get multiple documents that have my desired department_id (as well as documents with other department_ids) and that also match course_abbreviations such as "CS 301", "CS 322", "CS 365", etc.

Am I wrong to expect that my filtered query would produce the same documents as the non-filtered query sans the documents with other department_ids?

Comment: Initially, I am thinking you might need to apply a keywords analyzer to this field

Comment: So, if I use a "keyword" analyzer (along with a lowercase filter - [starts-with-phrase-matching](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/starts-with-phrase-matching/)), I get better results.  However, I would also like a match phrase query of "3" to give me 300 level courses when I provide a department_id filter; this doesn't work when I use this type of methodology.  Thanks.

Comment: in the past, i used bool or and filters to do this sort of thing. http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-filter.html / http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-and-filter.html... so many ways

Answer (score 0):

It's tough being completely sure what is going on w/o a curl recreation (http://www.elasticsearch.org/help), but based on the comments it sounds like you should use an edgengram analyzer. This works well on partial matches for terms in any part of the data.

My experience is that it is best to only apply the edgengram expansion while indexing (ie, in your index_analyzer). Search side, you just pass down the terms and try out a match query.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is due to the fact that elasticsearch will not consider all the suffixes of "CS 3". By default **only the first 50 suffixes will be considered**. If the documents containing the 50 suffixes selected by elasticsearch does not match on your `department_id` term query, then no results will be returned. In your case, if you have 3M documents, this does not seems unlikely.

You can increase the number of selected suffixes using the `match_expansions` parameter.

```
{
  "query":{
    "filtered":{
      "query":{
        "match_phrase_prefix":{
          "course_abbreviation":"CS 3",
          "match_expansions": 100
        }
      },
      "filter":{
        "term":{
          "department_id":49599
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Increasing parameter `match_expansions` will also make you request slower. See the documentation on [match_phrase_prefix](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html).